# Android animating a view with a fragment inside of it causing visual artifacts

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I currently have two fragments inside views. The views are animated around the screen.

On most devices there is no problem. However on some devices including the simulator, the visuals inside each of the fragments becomes jagged and smears while the animation is taking place. As soon as the animation is finished then it appears normally.

Im guessing that the draw commands inside the fragments are not getting called when the containing view is being animated. Is there any way I can force the fragments to redraw on every frame of the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to invalidate the parent view while animating.

Comment: @Carnal Thanks it worked! If you create an answer Il mark it correct. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidate your parent view while animating :)